# example for complex projective variety which is not the intersection of hypersurfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I am looking for examples of (irreducible) complex projective varieties which is not the intersection of hypersurfaces. I think that such variety exists, but I am not able to find any example.

Morever. if I asks the variety to be smooth, do examples still exists?

Comment: Using adjunction formula you can compute the genus of a curve which is a complete intersection. This implies that for example a smooth curve of genus $2$ is never a complete intersection.

Comment: Did you mean:"[...] which is not *complete* intersection of hypersurfaces"?

Comment: You can show that a complete intersection has very little (singular) cohomology and this can be a source of counterexamples; for example I think that abelian varieties are essentially never complete intersections (unless they are elliptic curves).